# Query condition missed key schema element: source_transaction_id in dynamoDB Scala

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to execute a query with secondary Index as following

```
val valMap = new ValueMap()
      .withString(":v_source_transaction_id", "843f45ad-cb1d-4f41-9ede-366c9304e447")
      //.withString(":source_transaction_trace_id","843f45ad-cb1d-4f41-9ede-366c9304e443")

println(valMap)
//search is defined then extract dates from search.. else continue with simple logic.
val keyConditionExpression =   """source_transaction_id =
                                 | :v_source_transaction_id""".stripMargin


val spec = new QuerySpec()
  .withProjectionExpression("source_transaction_id, transaction_date")
  .withKeyConditionExpression(keyConditionExpression)
  .withValueMap(valMap)
  .withMaxResultSize(2)


case class DataItems(transaction_date: String)
val itemList = new ListBuffer[DataItems]
val items = table.getIndex("gsi-settlement").query(spec)

println(table.getIndex("gsi-settlement"))

val iterator = items.iterator()
while (iterator.hasNext) {
  val next = iterator.next()
  itemList += DataItems(next.getString("transaction_date"))
}
itemList.foreach(println)
```

here gsi settlement is the secondary index and source transaction id is primary key and I am getting the following error:

```
[AmazonDynamoDBException: Query condition missed key schema element:  source_transaction_id
```

Comment: do you mean `GSI` by `secondary Index` ?

Comment: @AtulKumar yes its secondary Index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```java
val keyConditionExpression = """source_transaction_id = :v_source_transaction_id""".stripMargin
```

Currently your keyConditionExpression coming up as

```
source_transaction_id =
   :v_source_transaction_id
```

Error : `AmazonDynamoDBException: Query condition missed key schema element:  source_transaction_id` is suggesting that you are missing the GSI key in your query

Comment: that doesn't helps. if I try to query with primary index and its partition key.. things work fine